# Why we use Keypress Event and Key Codes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Tabbing is not working for textboxes in Mozilla  when I use this in my Javascript code:

```
function AttachKeyupEvent() {
    var textboxes = $("input[type=text][isautocomplete!=true]");

    /// regex excluding all foreign characters
    var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9\b\s \+\?\(\)*#;:\$@!\&=\\-.,'//]+$");

    $(textboxes).live('keypress', function (e) {
        var key = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
        var code = e.which || e.keyCode;
        /// code to check foreign characters code 46 is for delete 39 and 37 is for arrows (mozila spport)
        if (regex.test(key) || code == 46 || code == 39 || code == 37 || code == 92) {
            if (e.which != 0 && e.charCode != 0) {
                TriggerHandlers.call(this);
            }
        }
        else {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;   
        }
    });
```

But when I use this code in else part it works fine.

```
else {
    return true;   
}
});
```

Can please anyone give me proper explanation what exactly code doing? and why these keycode used here??

Comment: FYI: `live()` is **so** deprecated. Which version of jQuery are you on?

Comment: Your code is checking whether the entered value in textbox is within the specified format. If not,it doesnt allow you to type. This is what regex expression.

Comment: Thank you Alaksander..but what this code doing: $(textboxes).live('keypress', function (e) {
        var key = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
        var code = e.which || e.keyCode;
        /// code to check foreign characters code 46 is for delete 39 and 37 is for arrows (mozila spport)
        if (regex.test(key) || code == 46 || code == 39 || code == 37 || code == 92) {
            if (e.which != 0 && e.charCode != 0) {
                TriggerHandlers.call(this);
            }

Answer (score 0):

`e.preventDefault();` and `return false;` just blocks the further tabbing.

Answer (score 0):

`e.preventDefault();` as it's name suggest prevent the default behavior of the browser on the event, in this case going from field to field with tab.

Comment: Thank you all for your reply..Got it. Now can anyone please explain what the complete functionality of this code..Sorry I am new in Jquery world so